# Mvc ActionResult not passing back object on Post request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

My resister works perfectly when passing back the form, but one that I built it passes back nothing. I am not sure what I am doing differently than the register page that visual studio provided. It calls the right http post method but the value passed is null. thanks for any help. I just want that model to post back to the controller action result.

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Support()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }
          [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost, ValidateSpamPrevention]
        public ActionResult Support(QuickEmailModel email)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                 return View("thankyou", email);
            }
            return View(email);

        }
```

Model

```
public class QuickEmailModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company (Optional):")]
    public string Company { get; set; }
}
```

}

Top of View

```
@using PoliteCaptcha
@model Models.QuickEmailModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Support";
}
```

Bottom where the form is

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    @Html.ValidationSummary()
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Company, "Company (Optional):", new { @class = "control-label" })</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Company, new { @class = "span4" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email, "Email:", new { @class = "control-label" })
                        <div class="controls">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @Class = "span4" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Subject, "Subject:", new { @class = "control-label" })</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Subject, new { @class = "span4" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Subject, "Description:", new { @class = "control-label" })</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Description, new { @class = "span4", @rows = "6", id = "txtDescription" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @Html.SpamPreventionFields()
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" style="margin-right: 15em;
                        float: right;" />
                }
```

Comment: What is `ValidateSpamPrevention`?

Comment: ValidateSpamPrevention is an attribute from PoliteCaptcha nuget package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your parameter name is the same as one of your field names (email). Rename the Method parameter name to model (or something else besides email).

What I believe is happening is that the MVC model binder sees a posted value named "email" and it's trying to assign it to the parameter of the same name, but since it's not a string it can't do it.  Thus it assigns a null.

Also, model binding is case insensitive, so Email and email are the same.

Comment: What! Thank you that fixed it. So the problem was in my model I had a property called Email and my parameter email in my post method was conflicting? If so, is it not case sensitive?

Comment: @user516883 - Model binding is case insensitive because http posted values are case insensitive.  It's just how it is.  MVC is following the standard.

Comment: Wouldn't prefixing param names with "email." disambiguate that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the model mapper cannot map form name/value pairs from the POST request to an instance of QuickEmailModel object, and simply ignores them. Examine the POST request being sent in Firebug or other tool, what are the names of name/value pairs?

You should probably change your view like so:

```
@{ var email = ....; }

<label class="control-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => email.Company, "Company (Optional):", new { @class = "control-label" })
</label>
<div class="controls">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => email.Company, new { @class = "span4" })
</div>
```

because the name of your POST action param is "email". I think that this should force form param names to be "email.Company", etc. If not, try the other variant

```
@Html.TextBox("email.Company", model.Company)
```

Comment: Not sure I follow. whats that @{var email...;} at the top. Is that my 
@model Models.QuickEmailModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Support";
}

Comment: Also I would like to know what I did to screw this up from the beginning. I didnt do anything special. I am just really confused on why my MVC is the same as register but mine does not pass back value. The are pretty much duplicated

Comment: It should be `@{ var email = Model; }` in your razor view, before that first `<label>` tag (before the first usage of 'email' variable in some C# block). I just didn't know if you do anything else or just map to the @model so I wrote `...`.